# set ImagePath in viewmodel in silverlight application

Tags: c#, image, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

In One of the datagrid column I want to set the Image depending on the status(Active/InActive)
of the user..! status of the user is coming from the database.How to achieve this..??

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a cell template and put an image tag. Use converter which takes your original data coming from database. In the converter, based on the data return the image url to load.

Comment: Let me know if you still have problem, I can write a sample code for you.